# ¿por que no aparece la propiedad layout_weight en la paleta de propiedades?

Tags: android, android-layout

No aparece la propiedad `layout_weight` en la paleta de propiedades, mi versión de android es 2.2.3

Ha dejado de ser soportada esta propiedad para colocar el peso al layout?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si se encuentra pero debes buscarlo, ve la imagen que agrego, esta abajo de layout_gravity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight)

Sigue existiendo... te recomiendo cambiar la opción de DESIGN a TEXT (evitarás problemas como ese)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego ingresa la propiedad manualmente

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:text="ejemplo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debe aparecer en las propiedades, pero no se encuentra abajo de `layout_width` y `layout_height`, anexo una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]